# Unable to place landing component with no header

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to implement landing section where only after clicking the button in landing section it should redirect to recipes where it contains header part and all the recipes.The header should appear on recipes section, shopping list section ,signin and signup section. I am not able to understand where to implement the landing selector.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody please help me in placing  the landing selector so that it should not contain the header part

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean (something like isEndLandingSection) reachable in the needed components through a service. You set this variable to true when you click on the button of your landing section and simply use *ngIf to show or hide the header according to this boolean value.
This way, you don't need to change app.component.html, but header.component.html to add the *ngIf

Comment: I used a router and set a path {path:'',component:LandingComponent,pathMatch:'full'}. So whenever my application opens up it contains landing component.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the problem. What if you use the lifecycle hook **OnInit** in your header component, to set the boolean to false, and on the html of your header, you still use the *ngIf, which sould not display the element

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it. Can you please explain with a snippet